# Error while displaying table in python mysql

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x

I created a function called "display_table" to display any table , given its name. When I call this function to display a table called 'members', I get the following error.

> mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in >your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server >version for the right syntax to use near ''members'' at line

```
def display_table(table_name):
    sql = " select * from %s "
    val = (table_name,)
    mycursor.execute(sql,val)
    myresult = mycursor.fetchall()
    for row in myresult:
        print(row)


display_table('members')
```

I can't understand why this error shows up.
Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot pass a table name as a parameter to your prepared statement. Parameters are only allowed for column data. You should change your code:

```
def display_table(table_name):
    sql = " select * from %s " % table_name
    mycursor.execute(sql)
    myresult = mycursor.fetchall()
    for row in myresult:
        print(row)


display_table('members')
```